# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2 is not compatible with uap10.0.17134 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17134)

Tags: mysql, ef-core-5.0, winui-3

I am getting the following error while adding EF Core nuget package in a WinUI desktop application.

I am trying to access mysql from WinUI application using EF Core.

My dotnet version from command line is

> 5.0.200-preview.20601.7

```
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2 is not compatible with uap10.0.17134 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17134) / win10-x86-aot. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you intend to use .NET 5 (not UAP). See [Create a WinUI 3 desktop app for C# and .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/get-started-winui3-for-desktop#create-a-winui-3-desktop-app-for-c-and-net-5) to make sure you created your project correctly.